# Delphi large exponent extended value string conversion error

Tags: delphi

I am attempting to convert an extended value with a large exponent in Delphi 7 on Win 7-64 and am getting an "Invalid floating point operation" exception on what I believe is a valid value.  The value is 3.6854775808e-4912, which the debugger reports without a problem.

The following routines have been tried and all of them generate this exception:

FloatToStr   .
Format       .
FormatFloat  .
FloatToText  .

Anyone know what is going on?

EDIT:

I probably should have mentioned that I am searching a buffer for a particular extended value and the location can be at any offset in the buffer.  The method copies 10 bytes to a variant record and extracts an extended value from the record.  An attempt is then made to convert the extended value to a string using one of the routines mentioned above, which generates the error.  I have also discovered that attempting to multiply the value by 1.0 also generates the error.

```
TDecoderRec = record
  case integer of
     0 : ( Binary: TBinaryArray );
     1 : ( Character : TCharArray );
     2 : ( ShortIntVal: ShortInt );
     3 : ( ByteVal: Byte );
     4 : ( SmallIntVal: SmallInt );
     5 : ( WordVal: Word );
     6 : ( IntegerVal: Integer );
     7 : ( LongWordVal: LongWord );
     8 : ( Int64Val: Int64 );
     9 : ( SingleVal: Single );
    10 : ( Real48Val: Real48 );
    11 : ( RealVal: Real );
    12 : ( DoubleVal: Double );
    13 : ( CompVal: Comp );
    14 : ( CurrencyVal: Currency );
    15 : ( ExtendedVal: Extended );
end;  { TDecoderRec }

fldExtended.AsExtended:= DecoderRec.ExtendedVal;

procedure TCustomNumericEdit.SetAsExtended( Value: Extended );
begin
  AssignText( FloatToStr( Value ));  { <<---- FloatToStr causes the error }
end;  { TCustomNumericEdit.SetAsExtended }
```

These are the hex bytes comprising ExtendedVal:

```
74 02 08 03 54 6F 70 03 A4 00
```

This is the value that the debugger reports:

```
3.6854775808e-4882
```

---

```
program ProjectFloatError;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;
var
  Value : Extended;
  s     : String;
begin
  try
    Value.Bytes[0] := $74;
    Value.Bytes[1] := $02;
    Value.Bytes[2] := $08;
    Value.Bytes[3] := $03;
    Value.Bytes[4] := $54;
    Value.Bytes[5] := $6F;
    Value.Bytes[6] := $70;
    Value.Bytes[7] := $03;
    Value.Bytes[8] := $A4;
    Value.Bytes[9] := $00;
    s := FloatToStr( Value );  // <-- Invalid floating point operation
    WriteLn(s);
    ReadLn;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      ReadLn;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: This should all work. We can't see your code.

Comment: @DelphiFan: Is the error occurring when you are converting from `Extended` to `String`, or from `String` to `Extended`? If you are starting with an `Extended`, it does not make sense for any of those functions to fail when creating a `String`, since you already have the `Extended` in memory. But a `StrToFloat()` conversion certainly could fail if the value being represented is too high to fit in an `Extended`. Like David said, please show the actual code that is failing.

Comment: @David and Remy: I should have been more clear, sorry about that.  It looks like the ExtendedVal field of the record is truly returning an invalid combination of bytes.  The odd thing is that the debugger has no issues with it and displays a value that is within the acceptable range.

Comment: Why not show a short compilable example that exemplifies your problem?

Comment: Can you show the simple code like [http://pastebin.com/GJ79kzsF](http://pastebin.com/GJ79kzsF)? It works fine but it is FPC, not Delphi so I am sorry for some inconvenience. Ah, yes, adding `e := StrToFloat(s);` works fine too.

Comment: Sorry again.  I thought I had submitted an edit to the question but had failed to press the Save Edits button.  I am incompetent as a forum user.

Comment: Added a minimal compilable example to reproduce the error.

Comment: Sounds like you have an invalid floating point value.

Comment: @David - it may well be invalid but then you might reasonably expect the debugger to report this rather than misleading indicate some valid valid instead.  Interestingly [using Delphi XE4] for me the debugger reports an ever so slightly different mantissa and an exponent of -4883, rather than -4882..

Comment: @Deltics Yes, one would expect that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision

Comment: You have to explicitly check all parts of the extended float to verify that it is a legal value.

Comment: What you are attempting to do is not going to work. You'll find plenty of strings that when interpreted as 10 byte extended are valid values. This question is a direct consequence of you attempting to solve a problem the wrong way.

Answer (score 5):

The number you want to convert is an example of an **unnormal number** (see 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format).
All valid numeric extended values must have an explicitly stored 1 bit in the highest mantissa position (this is different to single and double, where the highest bit is implied and hidden but not stored).

If this bit is zero, the number is **unnormal**, Wiki says: *Only generated on the 8087 and 80287. The 80387 and later treat this as an invalid operand.*

Operations on such numbers used to be compiler-dependent, e.g. BP7 outputs
`?.?<000000000000E-4882`, but any 32+ Delphi raises an exception.

Comment: Well, that is almost correct, except that denormals don't have this bit set either, although they are valid extendeds. Denormals must have an exponent of all zeroes, (i.e. -16383), though.

Answer (score 0):

**Any** operation performed on that value results in a floating point exception, indicating that this is not a valid floating point value at all.

Assuming that the value you are searching for is valid and that the only issue is in the translation of that sequence of bytes to a representation in a floating point variable then if you are searching a record buffer for this particular sequence of bytes why do you need to convert to a floating point at all ?

You presumably know the string representation of the byte sequence if you are in a position to be searching for that byte sequence, so I do not see why there is any need for a runtime conversion from the known byte sequence to a known string representation.

Which then begs the question, if this sequence of bytes is not after all a valid **Extended** value then it appears that the entire basis for what you are trying to achieve is flawed and needs further consideration ?

Comment: What value do you get when you reverse the bytes. Perhaps the asker has failed to convert from network to host byte order.

Comment: @David: Reversing the order in a buffer and assigning to an extended variable by typecasting the buffer is reported as 3.6854775808e+4009 in the debugger ... RevExtended:= extended( Buffer );

Comment: That doesn't sound right either. I think it's time for us all to stop guessing and you to work out what these 10 bytes really are. Why are you using extended anyway?

Comment: @David - Yes, I thought of that and as DF says, you get a different result in the debugger (but still an invalid FP op error in the code) so I didn't think it worth even mentioning.  But I wonder if the number of bytes may be significant, if not the byte order.  Why does the OP believe this to be an 80-bit Extended as opposed to a Single, Double or other extended value (i.e. as in the general term "extended" to refer to floating point types in general, as opposed to "Extended", referring to the 64/80-bit Delphi/Pascal  type specifically)